# Wordpress Page has a chaotic Recent News Widget

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

For my work I'm being asked to edit a Wordpress website but there's NO documentation and NO organization whatsoever so editing it is a nightmare.

And it relies heavily on Widgets I don't really know how to use but I can't find any info other than like sites that used it too so I'm not sure what to edit and I'm terrified on breaking the site since it's already uploaded.

For the most part all I need to do is edit the way recent news display the dates

[image]

Like, delete the "ON ___ AGO" or be able to modify it to display with different words since the site is in spanish.

```
[trx_widget_recent_news style="news-announce" show_categories="" category="0" count="4" orderby="date" order="desc"]
```

But this is all the code I have for it and nothing tells me how to edit the format of the date display.

```
[vc_row full_width="stretch_row" hide_bg_image_on_tablet="" hide_bg_image_on_mobile="" row_delimiter="" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile="" hide_on_frontpage="" css=".vc_custom_1657334261997{background-color: #1a1d24 !important;}"][vc_column icons_position="left"][trx_widget_recent_news style="news-announce" show_categories="" category="0" count="4" orderby="date" order="desc"][vc_empty_space height="32 px" alter_height="medium" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile="1"][vc_single_image image="9793" img_size="full" alignment="center" onclick="custom_link" img_link_target="_blank" link="https://agricoladasam.com.mx/dasam/" css=".vc_custom_1658420299087{padding-top: 50px !important;padding-bottom: 50px !important;}"][vc_empty_space height="50px" alter_height="medium" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile=""][/vc_column][vc_column icons_position="left"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="2/3" icons_position="left"][vc_empty_space height="4em" alter_height="none" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile=""][vc_empty_space height="3.5em" alter_height="none" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile="1"][trx_sc_title title_style="default" link_style="default" title="Últimas Noticias" description="Del Sector"][trx_widget_recent_news style="news-announce" show_categories="1" category="56" orderby="none" order="asc"][vc_empty_space height="2.6em" alter_height="none" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile=""][vc_column_text]%%CONTENT%%[/vc_column_text][vc_empty_space height="3.5em" alter_height="none" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile="1"][/vc_column][vc_column width="1/3" icons_position="left"][vc_empty_space height="2em" alter_height="none" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile="1"][vc_empty_space height="3.6em" alter_height="none" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile="1"][vc_widget_sidebar sidebar_id="sidebar_widgets" el_class="widget_area"][vc_empty_space height="4em" alter_height="none" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile=""][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="2/3" icons_position="left"][vc_empty_space alter_height="medium" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile=""][vc_single_image image="11941" img_size="full" onclick="custom_link" img_link_target="_blank" link="https://contactostihl.com"][vc_empty_space alter_height="medium" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile=""][/vc_column][vc_column width="1/3" icons_position="left"][vc_empty_space alter_height="medium" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile=""][vc_single_image image="3670" img_size="medium"][vc_empty_space alter_height="medium" hide_on_desktop="" hide_on_notebook="" hide_on_tablet="" hide_on_mobile=""][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column icons_position="left"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

This is the mess I was left with, I feel someone did the block editing thingy and just left me to suffer. Lol.

Answer (score 1):

If the Site Language is Spanish, the rendering of *"on 21 horas ago"* could be altered by changing the [date/time](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/customize-date-and-time-format/) formats in:
**WP Admin > Settings > General**

*NB. This would affect all dates/times displayed on the site globally.*

Another option would be to search for the "trx_widget_recent_news" callback function in the plugin/theme directory to see exactly how the time in the widget is rendered. Depending on what you find, you could overwrite the [shortcode callback](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) with your own or [provide a translation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) for the function used.

Fortunately with WordPress, even when there is no documentation, you can always read the source code and use it as a guide to find your way around. Hope this helps you feel more confident - you can do it..